# APNS Emoji unicode \u and \U

Tags: unicode, encoding, apple-push-notifications, emoji

I have a messaging application and I have problems sending push notifications to ios with emoji text.
The following code for push works ( i tested it b writing manually in my php code and sent also manually to apple, received the message fine):
`"alert":"hi \ud83d\ude04"`.
But the code for push which comes from the device look like this: `"alert":"hi \Ud83d\Ude04"` ( \U instead of \u ). Messages with \U in text simply are not delivered!

The question is: is there a difference for apns between upper and lower literal in this case? If so, what is the best way to fix this problem? By that i mean shall i replace characters on the client or on the server. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use emojis with unicode 6.0 instead

Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji

Comment: can you give an example of how the alert body should look like with unicode 6.0?

Comment: "alert":"hi <0001f604>", 


<0001f604> is the Unicode code point for that character.The wikipedia entry about this references an EmojiSources.txt mapping file that you'll need to use to do the mapping yourself if you really need to get the old private-use character codes.